# Can't make custom roles for the user session Next-Auth

Tags: reactjs, authentication, session, next.js, next-auth

I'm using NextJs **next-auth** and I'm trying to make a custom Role and Id so I can save it along with the user Credentials in the Session, as always. It works fine But only when the user signup using the Credentials Provider.

My question is how can I get it to also save the user Credentials along the custom roles into the session when signing with Google Provider and other 3rd party Providers?

> My Code

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth/next'
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'

import db from '@/database/connect'
import Users from '@/database/modals/users'

import { compare } from 'bcryptjs'

import profilePictures from '../../../data/profilePictures.json'

const authOptions = {
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
        }),
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: 'Credentials',
            async authorize(credentials, req){
                await db.connect()

                // Check if user exist
                const results = await Users.findOne({email: credentials.email})
                if(!results){
                    throw new Error('No User Found With That Email!')
                }
                // Compare password
                const checkPassword = await compare(credentials.password, results.password)
                if(!checkPassword || results.email !== credentials.email){
                    throw new Error("Email Or Password Doesn't Match")
                }
                
                await db.disconnect()
                return results
            }
        })
    ],
    session: {
        strategy: 'jwt'
    },
    callbacks: {
        // Google signin function for saving the user info into the DB
        async signIn({ user }){
            // Check if user exist
            await db.connect()
            const results = await Users.findOne({email: user?.email})
            await db.disconnect()
            
            // Create the User and Post Into DB
            if(!results){
                try{
                    const userSchema = {
                        name: user?.name || '',
                        email: user?.email || '',
                        password: 'Signed using google',
                        picture: profilePictures[Math.floor(Math.random()*profilePictures.length)].path || '/images/TpAnime.jpg',
                        bookMark: {
                            animeList: [],
                            watchList: []
                        },
                        banned: false,
                        admin: false,
                    }
                    await db.connect()
                    Users.create(userSchema)
                }catch(err){
                    throw new Error("Something Went Wrong!, Try Signing With Another Account.")
                }
                return user
            }
            
        },
        
        // Checking and adding the some props from DB into the jwt token
        async jwt({token, user}){
            if(user?._id) token._id = user._id
            if(typeof user?.admin == "boolean") token.admin = user.admin
            if(typeof user?.banned == "boolean") token.banned = user.banned
            return token
        },
        // And then here I'm sending it to the session from the jwt
        async session({session, token}){
            if(token?._id) session.user._id = token._id
            if(typeof token?.admin == "boolean") session.user.admin = token.admin
            if(typeof token?.banned == "boolean") session.user.banned = token.banned
            return session
        } 
    },
    secret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_JWT_SECRET,
}
export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the user database schema you should have a role property. Usually default is "user". For example for `mongoose`

```
role: {
    type: String,
    default: "user",
  },
```

Now in `credentialsProvider`s `authorize` function when you fetch the user, user will already have `role` property so in `jwt` callback

```
jwt: async ({ token, user }) => {
   user && (token.user = user);
   return Promise.resolve(token);
},
```

when you write the token, it will already have `user.role` property

Comment: That didn't work

Comment: if you are using sql, you have to delete the db and re migrate it when you change the schema. if you are using nosql, make sure you saved a new user. its role property will be written to the token when that user logs in

Comment: I'm using Mongoose and I just deleted everything in the Users modal and restarted it still does not work, Only Credentials work and Google Provider is giving me a forbidden 403 Error now when I try to sign. I think the problem in the
 `async signIn({ user })` Function in the Callback object.